# Uniqueness in class members

Tags: c++, class

C++ newbie here, I want my class to refer to the same object for all instatiation with the same constructor parameter (e.g. if the object already exists, the new variable I'm instantiating should return the existing object rather than creating one with the same value). 
Is there a semantic way to do that, or is the best approach to keep a static vector which contains all objects in the class and check in the constructor if one exists with the same parameters?

Comment: You need  `Singleton class` : http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Singleton.html or google it!

Comment: Look up singleton pattern.

Comment: It's not a singleton if there are many of them...

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a hash from the parameters you can do some similar:

```
class YourClass
{
    static std::unordered_map< std::string, YourClass > s_instances; // You can use std::map as well

    static YourClass& get_instance( paramtype1 param1, paramtype2 param2 );

    static std::string create_hash( paramtype1 param1, paramtype2 param2 );
    // The implementation depends on the type of parameters
};

std::unordered_map< std::string, YourClass > YourType::s_instances;

YourClass& YourClass::get_instance( paramtype1 param1, paramtype2 param2 )
{
    auto hash = create_hash( param1, param2 );
    auto it = s_instances.find( hash );
    if ( it == s_instances.end( ) )
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    else
    {
        s_instances[ hash ] = YourType( param1, param2 );
        return s_instances[ hash ];
    }
}
```

Naturally there are tons of question what you have to answer:
1. Should this operation thread-safe? I.e. can be access by multiple threads parallel or not? If yes you should protect the `s_instances` against parallel modification.

2. How would the destruction phase look like? The static members are destructed in reverse order of creation and very hard to control when are they executed. This means that it is possible that some resource is already destructed which is needed in the destructor of `YourClass`. Because of that I suggest some controlled destruction phase where the `s_instances` elements are removed and destructed.